# Video Stream in GTK Window?

Tags: python, user-interface, video, gtk3, glade

Is there any way to embed a video stream (ffmpeg) in a GTK Window? Right now I am using Glade along with the Python GTK3 bindings, and I don't see any obvious methods provided by Glade.

Perhaps a library or something part of GTK3 not exposed in Glade?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is by using GStreamer. They have a few docs over it: http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Basic+tutorial+5%3A+GUI+toolkit+integration

Setting it in Glade directly probably won't be possible though.